# How to auto generate and save file to a folder on my server using Javascript

Tags: javascript

Please, I need help here. I am trying to get data from an API using JS and then automatically generate an HTML file that will be saved to a path /details on my shared hosting server. The script is structured such that upon entering an IP address, the API will return the IP details and then create an HTML file containing the details and redirect to the path /details/ip_addresshtml.

The issue is I have tried everything I know but it keeps generating and immediately downloading the HTML file but won't save to my desired path. Here is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>IP Details</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Enter IP Address</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="" onsubmit="getIPDetails(event)">
        <input type="text" name="ip" id="ipInput" placeholder="Enter IP Address" required>
        <button type="submit">Get Details</button>
    </form>

    <script>
        function getIPDetails(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var ip = document.getElementById("ipInput").value;
            var apiUrl = "https://ipapi.co/" + ip + "/json";

            fetch(apiUrl)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => generateHTMLFile(data))
                .catch(error => console.log(error));
        }

        function generateHTMLFile(ipDetails) {
            var ip = ipDetails['ip'];
            var filename = 'details/' + ip + '.html';
            var fileContent = generateHTMLContent(ipDetails);

            var element = document.createElement('a');
            element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(fileContent));
            element.setAttribute('download', filename);

            element.style.display = 'none';
            document.body.appendChild(element);

            element.click();

            document.body.removeChild(element);

            window.location.href = filename; // Redirect the user to the generated IP details file
        }

        function generateHTMLContent(ipDetails) {
            var htmlContent = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>IP Details - ${ipDetails['ip']}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>IP Details - ${ipDetails['ip']}</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Key</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </tr>`;

            var keys = Object.keys(ipDetails);
            keys.forEach(function(key) {
                htmlContent += `
        <tr>
            <td>${key}</td>
            <td>${ipDetails[key]}</td>
        </tr>`;
            });

            htmlContent += `
    </table>
</body>
</html>`;

            return htmlContent;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The client/browser has to send the file to the server and the server has to save the file.

Comment: …or even better (and much more secure!), the browser should send only the ip address to the server, and it should be the server that generates the file and saves it.